# Reading characters including white spaces and excluding newlines from file c++

Tags: c++, file, dictionary, char

As the title suggest I want to read every character from a file including the white spaces and excluding the new lines.

An example of how the file look.

```
     .       
##         . :
   #___-     
##
--------------
______________
```

I am then using a map to convert each character to an integer.

The map `std::map<char, int> map_converter;`

```
std::ifstream map("level_1.map");

for( int t = 0; t < TOTAL_TILES; t++ ) {
    int tileType = -1;
    char load_type = ' ';

    map >> load_type;
    tileType = map_converter.find(load_type)->second;
    tiles[t] = new Tile(x, y, tileType);
}
```

When I compile it I only get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)

How do I do?
`

Comment: `if (map_converter.find(load_type) == map_converter.end())` we will have an issue. It is not valid to call `second` on an end iterator.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get what you mean. I'm fairly new to C++. 

How should I fix this?

Comment: @DanAndreasson I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if [std::map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) fails to find the value it will return `std::map::end`. The issue with this is the assignment `tileType = std::map::end()->second` is not valid.

```
std::ifstream map("level_1.map");

for( int t = 0; t < TOTAL_TILES; t++ ) {
    int tileType = -1;
    char load_type = ' ';

    map >> std::noskipws >> load_type;

    if (map_converter.find(load_type) == map_converter.end()) {
        continue;
    }
    tileType = map_converter.find(load_type)->second; //this is now safe to do.
    tiles[t] = new Tile(x, y, tileType);
}
```

Comment: But one problem still is there, how do I not skip white spaces?

Comment: @DanAndreasson set the [noskipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) for your stream(`map >> std::noskipws;`)

Comment: Hmm. When I use noskipws I get the segmentation fault error once again.

Comment: @DanAndreasson Is the segfault in the same place, Can you post the line of code your getting the segfault.